# browser keeps downloading .svc files WCF

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, svc

Been doing this for hours now and it drives me nuts.

On windows 7 I installed IIS 7.5 through add windows features, also installed  WCF HTTP activation, also did all the command line registrations.

In VS 2013 I have a  WCF Services project that runes very fine when I run it in IIS express but I want to test it together with my front-end.

But when I browse to my .svc file in the browser it just keeps getting downloaded, been searching google but get wrong results all the time, hopefully! Someone can help me.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF Service is in .Net Framework **4.0/4.5**, then check the .Net Framework version in Application Pool.

If it is 2.xxxxxx, change it to 4.xxxxx.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Handler Mapping check if the request type is defined as (*.svc)